# Open Layers 4 fit to extent zoom too much out

Tags: openlayers

Working with OpenLayers 4.2.0, I have the extent `[-45930163.095729224, -3380418.677804029, -5390354.729126186, -3011487.2342575104]` which is a box around Santa Catarina state, Brazil. [image]

But instead of having the map center in this box, I'm actually being centered in Australia, which would be an outer extend, if that is the right word for it, such as the map center as:

[image]

My code is (ignore the extent visibility and the condition for "Infinity"):

```
        extent = [-45930163.095729224, -3380418.677804029, -5390354.729126186, -3011487.2342575104];
        if (extent[0] != "Infinity") {
            map.getView().fit(extent, {size: map.getSize(), padding: [15, 0, 0, 0]});
        }
```

I've already tried to use a `size` different than `map.getSize()`, but all I get is the map zoomed in Australia.

Since I can't comment, @bartvde: It didn't helped too much. Kind of zoomed in, but the center is still in Australia.

Comment: Check your extent coordinates @Fabiano. Those given in your question are not within the validity extent of the EPSG:3857 projection, and are definitely not the corners of the extent shown in your image.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `constrainResolution: false` in the options to fit (second argument).

Comment: thank you very much  @bartvde. i got here searching for a means to auto zoom so the extent of my layers would fit by default the entire map view. wish my comment will redirect here people searching the same.